# Html table elements not hiding

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have an HTML table :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>row1_el1</rd>
        <div class="rowA">
            <td>row1_el2</td>
            <td>row1_el3</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <div id="rowB">
            <td>row2_el1</td>
        </div>
        <div class="rowA">
            <td>row2_el2</td>
            <td>row2_el3</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowC">
        <td>row3_el1</td>
        <td>row3_el2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="hideButton">hide</button>
```

When I click the button, I want to hide some elements from the table :

```
$(function() {
    var hideThem = function() {
        $("#rowB").hide();
        $("#rowC").hide();
        $(".rowA").hide();
    };

    $("#hideButton").on('click', function() {
        hideThem();
    });
});
```

However, it's not working : `rowA` and `rowB` are still visible.

How can I effectively hide them ?

Comment: `'block's` is the mistake. change it to `'click'`

Comment: `'block's` should be `"click"`

Comment: Yeah, effing autocorrect...

Comment: why you use div in tr row

Comment: did you solve your question

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's .click() function instead of .on().

[Here is the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/) for how to simply implement the function!

Answer (score 0):

You might want a simple click function below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hideButton").click(function(){
        $("#rowB").hide();
        $("#rowC").hide();
        $(".rowA").hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hideButton").click(function(){
        $("#rowB").hide();
        $("#rowC").hide();
        $("#rowA").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr id="rowA">
        <td>row1_el1</rd>
        <td>row1_el2</td>
        <td>row1_el3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowB">
        <td>row2_el1</td>
        <td>row2_el2</td>
        <td>row2_el3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="rowC">
        <td>row3_el1</td>
        <td>row3_el2</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="hideButton">hide</button>
```